# How to lazy load (dynamically import) TinyMCE with webpack?

Tags: webpack, tinymce

Loading TinyMCE with webpack the standard way is pretty straightforward (as described here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/). This is my current code:

```
require.context(
    "file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]&context=node_modules/tinymce!tinymce/skins",
    true,
    /.*/
);
import "tinymce/tinymce";
import "tinymce/icons/default";
import "tinymce/themes/silver";
import "tinymce/plugins/link";
import "tinymce/plugins/paste";
import "tinymce/plugins/wordcount";
import "tinymce/plugins/image";
import { Editor as _Editor } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";
```

As the TinyMCE in my project is used in just a few places, I'd like to lazy load it - let's say in a React useEffect hook, something like this:

```
// here goes the require.context from the previous example

// this is inside a React.FC
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchModules = async () => {
        await import("tinymce/tinymce")
        await import("tinymce/icons/default")
        await import("tinymce/themes/silver")
        await import("tinymce/plugins/link")
        await import("tinymce/plugins/paste")
        await import("tinymce/plugins/wordcount")
        await import("tinymce/plugins/image")
        const { Editor: _Editor } = await import("@tinymce/tinymce-react");

        TinymceEditor.current = _Editor; // storing the class so I can render it afterwards

        setLoaded(true) // indicating that everything is loaded and ready to render
    };

    fetchModules()
}, [])
```

When TinyMCE starts up, it tries to load a skin. It works correctly in the first non-lazy example. But in the second example, it tries to load the skin relative to the current pathname instead of the webpack root (e.g. if the pathname is http://localhost:8080/example/, then it tries to pull a skin from http://localhost:8080/example//skins/ui/...).

How can one solve this issue? I'm open to any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using ReactJS, however I solved this by specifying the [skin_url](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#skin_url) property during tinymce initialization.

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    skin_url: 'http://localhost:8080/path/to/skins/'
});
```

Looking at the React integration [docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/#init), your init should look something like this

```
<Editor
  init={{
    ...
    skin_url: 'http://localhost:8080/path/to/skins/'
  }}
/>
```